# From JTextField to JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

In NetBeans I've created a project with many of `JTextField`'s. Now I understand that I should validate it. Is it possible to "cast" text fields to `JFormattedTextField`'s?

Comment: *"It is possible to "cast" text fields to JFormattedTextField's?"* No it's not. The other way around is possible though, given `JFormattedTextField` extends from `JTextField`.

Comment: So I must delete all JTexFields and add Formatted fields ?

Comment: Not necessarily but it's highly recommended. On the other hand you can let the class' variables declared as `JTextField` and initialize them as `JFormattedTextField` through custom code. Then you can "safely" down cast them as `JFormattedTextField` later. It sounds like a dirty workaround though.

Comment: Take a look at [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)

Comment: Can you actually tell me from which way you want to validate jTextfeild's value? Do you want it "enter only numbers" or "enter only string or characters"? If you want to validate your jTextFeild to "enter only number" there is other ways. No need to cast. Otherwise you can directly use jformattedTextfeild's formatterFactory option.

Comment: How 'many' of these are there?  Unless you can count many hundreds of them, I don't see the big deal.  Any decent IDE will allow a global replace, with individual confirmation, of JTextField with JFormattedTextField, and a hundred or two with visual inspection of each one shouldn't take more than an hour or two.  Of course you have other coding you want to do once these are declared the way you want them, but since JFormattedTextField extends JTextField (so all the JTextField method uses are still ok), I don't see why it would be a big deal just to change all the declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It is possible to "cast" text fields to `JFormattedTextField`'s?*

No it's not. At least not directly. The other way around is possible though, given `JFormattedTextField` extends from `JTextField`.

> *So I must delete all JTexFields and add Formatted fields ?*

Not necessarily but it's highly recommended. On the other hand you can let the class' variables declared as `JTextField` and initialize them as `JFormattedTextField` through custom code:

[image: Customize code]

[image: Code customizer]

Then you can "safely" downcast them as `JFormattedTextField` later. However I'd like to emphasize one more time that it sounds like a dirty workaround. Also note you won't be able to change the `setText(...)` code to `setValue(...)` which is preferred for formatted text fields.